# REST API Design: naming for all entities on url

Tags: rest, restful-url

Can "`ALL`" in the url below be used to represent all clients?

```
POST v1/all-clients/
```

Because the url below doesn't represent "`ALL`", it represents a collection of clients.

```
POST v1/clients/
```

Answer (score 0):

> Can "ALL" in the url below be used to represent all clients?

Yes.

REST doesn't care what spelling you use for your URI; you can use anything you like.

```
/v1/all-clients
/v1/all-clients/
/v1/clients/all
/v1/clients?all
/v1/all/clients/
/213fba61-ff84-4de1-ad36-7820ce347a92
```

Those are all *fine*.